# makefile rules in other rules

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile with two rules. i want to include one rule in another.
example:

```
   |--> compile:
   |        g++ main.cpp -o main
   |    run:
   -----    compile (should execute the compile rule)
            ./main
```

how do i do this?? because when i try to do this it doesn't work.
it gives me this error:

```
make: compile: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 127
```

the arrows and lines are just to point the rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common and trivial way to do this is to have one target depend on the other.

```
run: compile
    ./main
```

There is no need to name the `compile` rule separately, though.

```
run: main
    ./$<
```

(Obscurely but conveniently uses the first dependency as the name of the script to run. `make` probably already knows how to make `main` so you don't need to spell that out.)